# SQL my query return nothing

Tags: sql, join, phpmyadmin

My problem is when I execute it I wait a lot of time and it says it worked, but my table is not filled and it treated 0 rows.

This is my schema:

```
Divinite(ID,Name)

Navire(ID,Name)

Heros(ID,Name,Lastname)

Numr(ID,NR) // Roman(Numbers)
```

`Ecscales` and `Equipage` are the dumps I am getting information from
[image: Here is the image who shows what those columns contains]

```
INSERT INTO expedition (Numero,ID_divinite,ID_navire,ID_heros)
select numr.ID,divinite.ID,navire.ID,heros.ID
from numr
INNER JOIN equipage on equipage.expédition = numr.NR
INNER JOIN Divinite
INNER JOIN escales on escales.divinite = nom.divinite
INNER JOIN navire on equipage.bateau = Navire.nom
INNER JOIN heros on equipage.héros = CONCAT(heros.prenom,heros.nom)
WHERE equipage.expédition=escales.expédition
```

Comment: What are you joining 'INNER JOIN Divinite' on?

Comment: I am joining Divinite ON divinite.ID with romans letter  (numr)

Comment: I dont see any join to Divinite in your statement

Comment: Yes , because it will automaticly join my table on the .ID with the other joins

Comment: If you skip the `insert` for now and just run your `select...` does it produce any results? Perhaps your conditions for the joins intersect in the empty set. Without looking at the content of all of your tables involved in the joins, it's hard to tell just looking at your question.

Comment: I think the `inner join` without an `on` clause does a `cross join`.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. What SQL DBMS are you using?--please tag. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.